# ENQ at the end of string

Tags: c, string, posix

i got a stange behavior in my program, let me explain:

the function looks like this:

```
void PrintDirTree(const char* dirName, size_t depth)
```

then i have a while loop where i go trough the directory and make a new string for the next recursive call (printName is set before to 'examplefolder/'):

```
char* newDir = (char*)malloc(strlen(dirName) + strlen(dirEntry->d_name) + 1);
if (newDir != 0) {
    memset(newDir, 0, sizeof(*newDir));
    strcat(newDir, dirName);

    if (dirName[strlen(dirName)-1] != '/') {
        //printf("%d\n", dirName[strlen(dirName)-1]); <-- there i get the '5' 
        strcat(newDir, "/");
    }
    strcat(newDir, printName);
    PrintDirTree(newDir, depth + 1);
    free(newDir); newDir = 0;
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "error allocating memory\n");
    return;
}
```

sometimes (but every time on the same directory) i get a ENQ (integer 5) at the end of the string **dirName** that is put to the next function call.
this misbehavior results in a incorrect opendir() call.

Comment: Won't you need at least strlen(dirName) + strlen(...->d_name) + *2*?  One byte for the terminal '\0' and one for a possible '/' path separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dirName` may be "".  Need to insure you do not access *before* the beginning of the array.

```
// if (dirName[strlen(dirName)-1] != '/')
if (dirName[0] && dirName[strlen(dirName)-1] != '/')
```

`malloc()` is too small.  Need 1 for the potential `/`.
BTW: How are `printName` related `dirEntry->d_name`?

```
// char* newDir = (char*)malloc(strlen(dirName) + strlen(dirEntry->d_name) + 1);
char* newDir = malloc(strlen(dirName) + strlen(printName) + 1 + 1);
```

@fpw is correct about initializing.

```
// memset(newDir, 0, sizeof(*newDir));
// strcat(newDir, dirName);
strcpy(newDir, dirName);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing the memory using

```
memset(newDir, 0, sizeof(*newDir));
```

This doesn't clear the entire memory because *newDir is only a single character. As you start to write into the array, you're overwriting the initial zero and are thus in pseudo-random data. Clear it using the correct size or use calloc instead of malloc.